# How to use the Command Pattern with GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, command-pattern

I've been watching a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM) on implementing the command pattern in GWT, but I could use some help in understanding it. Specifically, the video talks about how the command pattern can be used to cache / make batch requests, implement undo functionality, etc. But I'm just not seeing how its any different from using regular GWT-RPC requests.

In the video, he wants to implement a service which will send over an `ArrayList<ContactId>` and return an `ArrayList<Contact>` for an address book. Here's how he's doing it:

1) Define two interfaces, `Action` and `Response` as follows:

```
interface Response { }

interface Action <T extends Response> { }
```

2) Create the following RPC service for getting the contact details:

```
interface ContactsService extends RemoteService
{
    <T extends Response> T execute( Action<T> action );
}

interface ContactsServiceAsync
{
  <T extends Response> void execute( Action<T> action, 
                                    AsyncCallback<T> callback);
}
```

3) Create the following `Action` class:

```
class GetContacts implements Action<GetContactsResponse>
{
   public ArrayList<ContactId> getContactIds(){...}
}
```

4) And the following `Response` class:

```
class GetContactsResponse implements Response
{
    public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {...}
}
```

5) To execute it, he does the following:

```
service.execute( new GetContacts(), new AsyncCallback...);
```

My question is, how does doing all of this help towards caching the requests, batching them, or implementing undo functionality?

If someone could explain it for me, that'd be great..

Answer (score 1):

What you done is unification of your RPC calls. This unification gives you ability to add later some generic code for all RPC calls. This generic code (dispatcher) will be responsible for:

- batching the requests
- caching the requests

You can see an exemple of the code for dispatcher in [this blog post](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/caching-batching-dispatcher-for-gwt-dispatch/).

[Here you can find a library](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't help if your `service` instance in your last step is just the result of `GWT.create(ContactsService.class)`. But you can implement `ContactsServiceImpl` yourself (or through a generator) that wraps the *real* RPC implementation and adds caching and batching. See [slide 46](http://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/Th_0200_GoogleWebToolkitArchitecture-BestPracticesForArchitectingYourGWTApp.pdf), around 20:30 in the video for an example with caching. Batching could be explicit (a command containing other commands), or implicit (hidden within your service wrapper implementation, triggered with `scheduleFinally` or after a small delay)

Re. undo, because all your arguments (arguably here a single one) are bundled in a single request object, you could pass it as-is to an `undo()` method (instead of `service()`). Of course, implementing an *undo* functionality is much more work than just sending a command, but at least you don't have to implement an undo method for each and every action that could be cancelled.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `ContactServiceImpl` could wrap the real RPC implementation, etc? Also, Slide 46 seems to be the one talking about event bus? I don't see any caching related to GWT services there.

Comment: That `execute()` method on slides 46 and 47 is the one from the wrapping implementation, calling down to the `realService` and `recache()`ing the result before calling the original callback.